# Jenkins checkout scm: how to get tags?

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkinsfile, I have below, which seems to clone the latest version that triggered the Jenkins build. However, it did not fetch any tags.

Is there a way to customize `checkout scm` to fetch all git tags?

```
stage('Checkout') {
  steps {
    checkout scm
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the following also works for an explicit `checkout scm` but it works for the automatic checkout (`Declarative: Checkout SCM`).

Go to the configuration of the multi-branch -> `Branch Sources` -> `Git`.
Then add the options `Advanced clone behaviours` and then mark the checkbox `Fetch tags`.

[image: Marked checkbox]

I could not find an easy solution to enable this in the Jenkinsfile directly.
[This comment](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-45164?focusedCommentId=308009&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-308009) seems to be a possibility to also fetch the tags from the Jenkinsfile, but I have not tried it out.

Answer (score 1):

More of a workaround than an answer, but I just added `git fetch --all --tags` after the above step.

Comment: You are using declarative pipeline right? We are using scripted pipeline and then it can be achieved with a custom checkout with `[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false]` option set.
Full "code" we use should look like `def scmVars = checkout([$class:'GitSCM', branches: scm.branches, extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false]], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'id', url: 'url']] ])`. I only don't know if that can be used within declarative but now you can test it out.